# Reload a dataset each time a child form is opened

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am making a simple database driven data entry system. I have MDI form which has two children linked to it. FormOne is a simple form that updates an Access database using OleDbConnection. FormTwo is for viewing the Database using a DataGridView which is linked to a TableAdapter and a Dataset for the Access database.

I am facing this problem. Whenever I open FormOne and add an entry to the database, it gets added successfully but then if I open FormTwo (the one with DataGridView) I am unable to see the new entry in this DataGridView unless I restart the program.

I have a feeling that this is happening because .NET may be loading the DataSet only when the application is initially started and therefore it does not make any changes to the DataSet when the database is changed at runtime. (I may be wrong)

Can you help me out why this is happening and a possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to query the db to fill your dataset in FormTwo's VisibleChanged event handler when Visible is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `datagridview` load or link in the event:

```
Private Sub FormTwo_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
```